# How to stop scroll action in HTML label default click event

Tags: javascript, html

A simple case below, just scroll down to div like this and click the text, the page will scroll into label automatically. So how to stop it?

PS: preventDefault will block onchange event, so it can not be fixed by this simple way.

[image]

```js
const label = document.querySelector("label")
label.addEventListener("click", e => e.preventDefault())
const input = document.querySelector("input")
input.addEventListener("change", e => {
  e.target.checked = !e.target.checked
  console.log("change happen")
})
```

```html
<div style="height: 2000px">
  <label>
      <input checked type="radio" />
      <div>
        haha
      </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.   When you click a `label` (as opposed to a `span` or `div`) it has a special action.  That action is to put focus in the label's related input - as you've nested that input rather than use `for=` the browser focuses the input (a simple radio?)  and in order to focus it, it has to bring it into the display, so it "scrolls" to the *input*.   What are you *expecting* to happen?  If you don't want a `label` to work like a `label` then don't use a `label`.

Comment: I want to stop scroll action when click the content, I am not very sure about the label input rules so I am wondering if I can extract div tag out of the label tag (make label rendering alone), maybe it is right.

Comment: Change `<label>` to `<div>` or remove the `<input>`

Comment: It not specifically scrolling when you click, it's scrolling when the `input` gets focus.  Not much you can do about that as why would you want an input to have focus but not be visible on the screen?

Comment: Yep, I think from the component library design, the radio should be hidden, and it's label should be set in `<div>`, so from my mind the main reasonable structure is `<div><label><input hidden /></label><div onclickhere>text..</div></div>`